# PHP Mail() Function with headers

Tags: php

I always struggle when using headers along with the PHP mail() function.
The problem is that the headers are simply displayed in the email message.

**Example received mail :**

http://nl.tinypic.com/view.php?pic=63va5z&s=8#.U8PmeED8rbw

**Source :**

```
$onderwerp = "Bedankt voor uw bestelling met order nummer # ".$row['id'];
$ontvanger = "customer@customer.be";
$reply = "reply@reply.be";
//$reply = htmlspecialchars($_POST['je_email']); 
                                  
$headers = "Content-type: text/html; charset=iso-8859-1\r\n"; 
$headers .= "MIME-Version: 1.0\r\n";    
                             
$headers .= "Reply-To: Webmaster < reply@website.be >\r\n"; // reply-adres
//$headers .= "Cc:  webmaster@website.be , crewlid@website.be \r\n"; //copy
//$headers .= "Bcc:  crew@website.be \r\n"; // blind copy
$headers .= "From: TEST SOME NAME | GW8 <$reply>\r\n"; // de afzender van de mail
$headers .= "X-Mailer: PHP/" . phpversion() . "\r\n";
$headers .= "X-Priority: 1\r\n"; // 3 voor onbelangrijk 
$headers .= "Priority: Urgent\r\n";
$headers .= "Importance: High\r\n"; // Low voor onbelangrijk
$headers .= "X-MSMail-Priority: High\r\n"; // Low voor onbelangrijk  
                                  
$bericht = "<strong>TEST</strong>"; 
                                  
mail($ontvanger,$onderwerp,$bericht,$headers);
```

Which snippet I use, always the same problem..
Headers displayed in email content, as shown in screenshot.

Does anybody know how I can fix this ? I have a strong feeling this is a server-side problem..

Comment: Headers look okay to me. But I recommend a mail lib like SwiftMailer or PHPMailer anyway. And if I were you I would not send the PHP version with each e-mail due to security risks.

Comment: Try taking out each line in the headers until it works. Then you know which one is breaking stuff.

Comment: Allready changed and tried this.. The order/sequence seems to make a difference.

Comment: Are there any difficult characters hidden in one of your $headers lines? Something we can not see here because of different code pages?

Answer (score 0):

It would be better to use established mailing solutions instead of PHPs `mail()` function if you're not experienced with that.

A few hints:

**Readability and preventing errors**

For readability and programming purposes - think about implementing the headers as array. Instead of adding `\r\n` in every line you could work like that. When building together the mail in the `mail()` function you can `implode()` it.

```
// Building headers.
$headers = array();
$headers[] = 'MIME-Version: 1.0';
$headers[] = 'Content-type: text/html; charset=iso-8859';
$headers[] = 'X-Mailer: PHP/'. phpversion();
// ...

// Sending mail.
mail($ontvanger, $onderwerp, $bericht, implode(PHP_EOL, $headers));
```

**Sending HTML mails**

I recommend to send the mails as `multipart MIME messages` when sending html. This differs from your approch. Because it's not that easy to explain in a message. Maybe try it with that link: http://webcheatsheet.com/php/send_email_text_html_attachment.php

I've used multipart mime messages for example to send HTML mails with custom attachments via PHP.

There is no necessarity of paying attention to the order of the different headers. But it's some sort of a good practice to group them and start with the most important ones.

Comment: Documentation states you have to use `\r\n`, so using that constant might break it on certain OS.

Comment: In addition to being much more readable, loading the headers into an array will also make it easier to sanitize them before including them in the message. The problem is probably stray CRLFs in the headers somewhere.

Comment: @user3710844 My answer to your question was to write multipart mime messages. I've never had any problems writing HTML mails as multipart mime messages. But that might be difficult for the first time for you - but you say you're experienced... so ;-). Apart from that: many mail servers drop  mails (especially with high priority) which are not from the appropriate mail server. The do a reverse lookup seeing if your mx record matches the webserver and drop it if it doesn't match.